# ChessCafe.com RIP?

Tags: websites

The latest ChessCafe.com article - https://chesscafe.com/the-skittles-room/on-hiatus/ - has this to say:

> We would like to thank those who have supported ChessCafe with a
>   purchase of product and subsequent membership. However, subscriptions
>   have fallen just shy of what is needed to maintain our stable of great
>   columnists. Therefore, we are taking a three-month hiatus from posting
>   new content

I suspect "just shy" is a euphemism.

Does anybody have better information on when / whether ChessCafe.com is going to come back to life?

Comment: RIP chesscafe.com. People generally don't pay for articles like that. There're a dozen free and a few other paid chess e-magazines.

Comment: There are just too many Chess sites that require now a membership if you want good quality chess articles. ChessCafe was always my fav free site, i did support them by ordering many books from them. But I joined Chess.com a while back and there is really no reason to join the paid membership on Chesscafe since for the most part they have the same articles, just different writers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tim Harding, one of the writers for ChessCafe.com, [reports that he hasn't been paid for the last two articles he wrote](http://www.ecforum.org.uk/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6245&sid=16a86ce9a01d69bf680a253b15091d54&start=30#p164200). The conclusion has to be that it isn't coming back.

The internet is free and people are very reluctant to pay for content, even content as good as that which was provided by ChessCafe.com.